# Python ZeroMQ REQ/REP client bind waiting forever

Tags: python, zeromq

I'm just trying out zeromq for a project in python. I'm trying to bind the 'client' side and connect the server to the fixed location. I have a simple REQ/REP setup that works fine locally but seems to do nothing over a network. If I reverse the binding, then this also works over the network.

The relevant code is:

```
def respond(sock):
    message = sock.recv()
    response = "world"
    sock.send(response)
    print("Received '{0:s}', sent '{1:s}'.".format(message, response) )

def request(sock):
    message = "Hello"
    sock.send(message)
    response = sock.recv()
    print("Sent '{0:s}', recieved '{1:s}'".format(message, response) )

def main():
    opts = get_opts()
    if opts.client:
        sock = CONTEXT.socket(zmq.REQ)
        sock.bind("tcp://*:{0:d}".format(opts.port) )
        request(sock)
    if opts.server:
        sock = CONTEXT.socket(zmq.REP)
        sock.connect("tcp://{0:s}:{1:d}".format(opts.address, opts.port) )
        while True:
            respond(sock)
```

And a (non-)working example is here: https://gist.github.com/4071783

When connecting to a remote address, nothing seems to happen. If I check with tcpdump, I can certainly see activity on the port:

```
12:20:18.846927 IP server.58387 > client.5555: Flags [.], ack 1, win 3650, options [nop,nop,TS val 718051 ecr 46170252], length 0
12:20:18.847156 IP client.5555 > server.58387: Flags [P.], seq 1:3, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 46170252 ecr 718051], length 2
12:20:18.847349 IP server.58387 > client.5555: Flags [P.], seq 1:3, ack 1, win 3650, options [nop,nop,TS val 718051 ecr 46170252], length 2
12:20:18.847373 IP client.5555 > server.58387: Flags [.], ack 3, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 46170252 ecr 718051], length 0
12:20:18.847553 IP client.5555 > server.58387: Flags [P.], seq 3:16, ack 3, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 46170252 ecr 718051], length 13
12:20:18.847645 IP server.58387 > client.5555: Flags [.], ack 3, win 3650, options [nop,nop,TS val 718051 ecr 46170252], length 0
12:20:18.848286 IP server.58387 > client.5555: Flags [.], ack 16, win 3650, options [nop,nop,TS val 718051 ecr 46170252], length 0
```

But the `send()` and `recv()` are still blocked as if waiting for a connection. Does anyone know what this is or could suggest how to debug it?

Comment: In fact I just re-tested the zguide examples and the hwserver/client examples also only work in one direction. Hosting the server on one of my machines leads to both client and server waiting forever.

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping the remote address? 0MQ is just using TCP at this level so if the connect fails, it's because the address you're trying to connect to is not reachable.

Comment: I can connect successfully in the reverse direction. I.e. machineB can bind and have machineA connect to it. However this makes no sense for my application. I want machineA to bind and machineB to connect to machineAs address. When I try this, I see TCP traffic as normal (see the TCPdump in the question) yet 0MQ never seems to receive it. - If it helps, machineA is a RaspberryPi running pyzmq==2.2.0.1, machineB is a laptop running pyzmq==2.1.9

Comment: You didn't tell me whether "ping" works to the remote address.

Comment: Sorry, yes: machineA can ping machineB's address and machineB can ping machineA's address.

Comment: So if ping works but connections don't, it's perhaps a firewall or NAT issue. I.e. the inbound connection isn't being passed to the peer that bound its socket.